# Jumpbutton with GroundCheck

Tags: unity-game-engine

---

Hey guys, I really new to unity and had a question about my button.
I´ve added a joystick which only controlls my player in the horizontal axes and wanted to implement a jump button. My JumpScript ist currently like that:
[jumpscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzqI7.png)
The problem is, that the player can jump as much as he wants and this is not what I want. How do I make a groundcheck ?
[picture of my game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoO3X.png)

---

Answer (score 0):

Put a collider on your players feet and jump only OnCollisionStay with the ground. It should do the trick. Like in here [Unity 3D: How to stop being able to jump in the air](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62238783/3494306)