# Unity 3D: How to stop being able to jump in the air

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to achieve jumping on a 2d sprite in 3d world.
I can jump fine but I'm able to keep jumping in the air which I do not want.
I've been trying to find the problem for hours but still cannot come up with a solution.

```
{ 
   public float jumpHeight = 5f;
    public static bool isJumping = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && (isJumping == false))
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpHeight), ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isJumping = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you debugged and checked that the code in `OnCollisionExit` is ever called?

Comment: I'm sorry I am very new to unity and C# how would I go about doing that? Would I just write debug code into the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a collider as trigger on your 2D object and check if it is colliding with the terrain or ground. Only then you can jump. The same could be done with a Ray which collides with the ground. You dont need to use both just jump OnCollisionStay and thats it

Comment: I've tried to put the trigger on the collider but I fall through the ground when I do it.

Comment: Put your if logic in Update inside OnCollisionStay and it should do the trick

Comment: Without isJumping

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you very much.